# Update db row on login

Tags: php

I have the following code: its purpose is very clear => at login update db with +1 logins for totallogins and record the time of the very last login. The only downside is that it wont work.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam'); 

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
$Timesloggedin = "SELECT * FROM members.Timesloggedin WHERE Email='$email'";
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$query1 = "UPDATE members SET Timesloggedin = $Timesloggedin + 1, Lastloggedin = $time WHERE Email ='$email'";

$result_insert_loggedins = mysql_query($query1);
if (!$result_insert_loggedins) {
    echo 'Query failed';
}

if (mysql_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) 
{ 
    //If the Insert Query was successfull.
} 
?>
```

Comment: "it wont work" is not useful to those trying to help - what errors do you see?  have you checked log files?

Comment: Your first query seems bogus. Try this instead : "SELECT Timesloggedin FROM members WHERE Email='$email'"

Comment: To begin, you haven't executed the query shown in `$Timesloggedin`, you've only stated the SQL code for it.

Comment: your query is wrong, print the errory and you will see.

Comment: You should put parens around $Timesloggedin in $query1.

Comment: In fact, you don't even have to do that first query : just use "UPDATE members SET Timesloggedin = Timesloggedin + 1, Lastloggedin = $time WHERE Email ='$email'" for query1 and the value will be updated.

Comment: I can't believe this question went 10 minutes without someone lecturing you on the use of mysqli or PDO. mysql_ functions are antiquated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Well, thanks everyone for their help. I think the query now is allright but something else in my script is not correct. I also know I should have been more clear in the first place, but it was pretty late yesterday. ;)

Comment: Did you get that problem solved eventually? Was any answer useful?

Comment: @didierc, yes this is from a long time ago. I just selected the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query1 = "UPDATE members SET Timesloggedin = Timesloggedin + 1, Lastloggedin = '$time' WHERE Email ='$email'";
```

Remember that $time is a string and needs the quotes. Also, $Timesloggedin would be an object (if you actually ran the query which you don't) so just remove the $ and it will just increment the field.

Also, you don't even need the first query. Nor do you need the date calculation. Just use mysql's NOW()...

```
$query1 = "UPDATE members SET Timesloggedin = Timesloggedin + 1, Lastloggedin = NOW() WHERE Email ='$email'";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use

```
Timesloggedin = Timesloggedin + 1
```

Instead of the variable.